# semi random order

Tags: mysql, serialization, sql-order-by

i need to implement a semi-random sort of list,
I need to be able to fix x items as the first ones, and the rest to be ordered by random

question,

will something like

```
"..ORDER BY fixed DESC, rand"
```

where fixed is a boolean?

if not, how would you suggest?

Comment: Should work just fine with a small correction: `ORDER BY fixed DESC, RAND()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Jon's comment,

```
@rank:= 0; 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT @rank:= @rank +1 as rank, * FROM table1 
  ) s ORDER BY (s.rank < 10) DESC, RAND()
```

Will work, however, this will force a sort on a random order for the full table.

The following will be much faster.

```
@rank:= 0; 
SELECT s.* FROM 
  (
  SELECT @rank:= @rank +1 as rank, * FROM table1 LIMIT 200
  ) s
ORDER BY (s.rank < 10) DESC, RAND();
```

Because this will only sort 200 items and not the full table.

Comment: i don't understand what is this @ about... :$ btw, the list will be about max 20 items

Comment: @Toni, some people have 1 million records, the first query will be very very slow with many records, the second much less so.